# CometCloud installation, and possible alternatives

Tags: cloud

How do I install CometCloud by Rutgers University? (If there is some problem with the subversion) could you suggest me any alternatives to cometcloud?

CometCloud is an autonomic framework for enabling real-world applications on dynamically federated, hybrid infrastructure integrating (public & private) clouds, data-centers and Grids.